# Why are actual prescription lenses for myopia almost plano concave with the curvier face near the eye?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, vision

In a recent revision of the chapter on spherical aberrations in lenses, I found that the lens with minimum aberration will be the one in which the curvier side faces the incident ray.

This is shown in the following diagrams from my book that use a plano-convex lens for example.

[image]

Then I looked at my eyeglasses. I have myopia. The lenses (Tokai Lutina 1.67 fibre) I wear appear to be almost Plano-concave with the curvier (concave) face near my eyes.

Please help me understand why my lens maker (Tokai) makes lenses that go against the theory?

Comment: In your book, how many lenses are used to create the image? For eyesight, there are two lenses, the glasses and the eye lens, that form the image on the retina. If there's a diagram in your book, copy it here.

Comment: In my book, it's just one lens, a plano-convex lens in two situations where it is shown that if the curvier side faces the incident rays, the spherical aberration is less. I am only concerned with the spherical aberration by the lens in the eyeglasses. Updating my question with the diagrams you asked for.